# "Reenter your credential" error in Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create a ASP.net Web application, that I want to host on Windows Azure. When I click on "Host in cloud" check box, I get another dialog box, in which I enter my correct credentials of Windows.(I am using organization's email address in this case.). After I enter the credentials, I see the error "Reenter your credentials" error blow the combo box. When I hover the mouse pointer on this error, it reads "We need to refresh the credentials for this account".  In google chrome, I am able to log into windows azure portal with my organization ID. Could anyone help me understand this error?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Were you able to get a resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any resolution for this issue.

Comment: Just did a full clean install and have the same error. Did anyone get a fix?